# Magento 2 import csv

Tags: magento-2.1, import

I have a product CSV where sku, name and an attribute created by me are specified.

When I import the CSV, it gives an error saying

```
1. Specified URL key already exists in row(s): 637, 640, 677, 909, 1091, 1331, 1452, 1454, 1457, 1459, 1587, 1588, 1593, 1594, 1596, 1597, 1599, 1600, 1602, 1603, 1605, 1606, 1608, 1609, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1669, 1671, 1673, 1674, 1675, 1676, 1677, 1678, 1679, 1680, 1681, 1683, 1684, 1707, 1708, 1710, 1711, 1713, 1714, 1823, 1859, 1860, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 1881, 2016, 2017, 2038, 2039, 2040, 2041, 2042, 2043, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048, 2078, 2101, 2112, 2113, 2114, 2115, 2126, 2129, 2130, 2131, 2132, 2133, 2137, 2154, 2160, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2425, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2618, 2963, 3046, 3262, 827, 1586, 1592, 1598, 1601, 1604, 825, 828, 1667, 1615, 1666, 1668, 1613, 1670, 1706, 1709, 1712, 1312, 674, 1168, 1172, 1181, 1182, 924, 1270, 639, 636, 3285, 2537, 3182
2. Product Type is invalid or not supported in row(s): 2186, 2233, 2352, 2403, 2408, 2413, 2418, 2423, 2427, 2432, 2644, 2744, 3182, 3282, 3285, 3288, 3293, 3300, 3320, 3330.
```

I think that by not specifying url_key, it defaults to the name with hyphens. I do not want this to happen because the url has been specifically placed.

How can I import the CSV without overwriting the url?

Comment: you have to keep unique name in name column

Comment: but i want that url not rewrite